# Load MAX value from sql table into a DataTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, aggregate-functions

I need to reed aggregated data from SQL into .Net, to do this I use a `DataAdapter` to `Fill` a `DataTable`. The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT ACTNUMBR AS [SegmentNumber], MAX(DSCRIPTN) AS [Description], COUNT(*) AS [UsageCount]
```

The SegementNumber and the UsageCount values load into the DataTable as expected, but I cannot get the Description column to load values, it remains blank (running the query in SQL does return values). If I hardcode a value then it loads the values into the `DataTable` but as soon as I use a `MAX()` expression it does not load.

I have tried specifying the column detail for the `DataTable` but it had no effect.

Is this known behavior? How do I fix / work around it?

Comment: Is the description column a varchar(max) or text type in the db?

Comment: @Sico - it is char(60)

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, quite complicated, but pls ignore the question for now

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your SQL.  You can't include an aggregate function (MAX) without doing a group BY.

```
SELECT ACTNUMBR AS [SegmentNumber], 
       MAX(DSCRIPTN) AS [Description], 
       COUNT(*) AS [UsageCount]
FROM   SOMETABLE
GROUP BY ACTNUMBR
```

Comment: Thanks Bill but like I said (maybe not clearly enough), running the query in SQL (SSMS) does give data. I have only shown the select part.